# Previsão de volume de tráfego

Tags: r, series-temporais

Olá, boa tarde! Estou desenvolvendo um modelo que irá prever o volume de veículos a cada dia do ano, mas estou encontrando dificuldades por conta das funções que fazem as previsões dessazonalizadas e que não comportam a quantidade inputs. Alguém tem alguma outra ideia de como posso tratar esses dados para realizar a predição em modelos como o ARIMA, x13 Seats ou algum outro comando que faça o trabalho de maneira semelhante?

Segue adiante o meu código e os erros para cada tentativa:

```
library(forecast)

Pedagiados=data[,2]
Pedagiados=as.numeric(unlist(Pedagiados)
Pedagiados_TS=ts(Pedagiados,start = c(2015,1),end=c(2019,365),frequency=365)

plot(Pedagiados_TS,xlab='tempo',ylab='Volume',main='Volume 2015-2019')

ajuste=HoltWinters(Pedagiados_TS)
ajuste
prev_hw=forecast(ajuste,h=84,level=95)
plot(prev_hw,xlab='tempo',ylab='Volume',main='Volume veículos ')
prev_hw
require(xlsx)
write.csv2(data.frame(prev_hw),"Previsão HW 1T 2020.csv")

#SARIMA
fit.Volume=Arima(Pedagiados_TS,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal = c(1,1,1), method="ML",lambda=0)
```

> Error in makeARIMA(trarma[[1L]], trarma[[2L]], Delta, kappa, SSinit) : 
>     intervalo máximo suportado é 350

Com esse erro, tento ajustar pelo X13 ARIMA SEATS da seguinte forma:

```
#X13 ARIMA SEATS
require(seasonal)
ajuste_X13=seas(Pedagiados_TS)
```

No entanto:

> ```
> Erro: X-13 run failed
>
> Errors:
> - Seasonal period too large. See Section 2.7 of the Reference Manual on program limits
> - Time series could not be read due to previously found errors
> - Specify series before user-defined adjustments
> - Need to specify a series to identify outliers
> ```

Alguma sugestão de como analisar essa série temporal considerando a sua sazonalidade e realizando projeções?
Desde já agradeço

Comment: Fica difícil reproduzir o problema sem os seus dados (os problemas parecem estar ai). Por favor,  edite sua pergunta incluindo o resultado de `dput(data[,2])`. Se não puder compartilhar os dados, tente encontrar um conjunto público que reproduza o problema.